# The lockdown glitch in new Vegas

Tags: ps3, fallout-new-vegas

I went to to McNamara and he's in the process of doing the lock down thing.  I tried going out, waiting 3 days or more, and all that stuff but it's not working. And now I'm at the point where I either kill the BOS or have them be aligned with the NCR. But literally several hours of game play later he's still trying to lift the lockdown?!

Pleassseeeeee tell me there is a way around this because I am losing my mind!  I'm not sure what's wrong, I just need help. I have it for my ps3.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Fallout New Vegas Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Nolan_McNamara) removing the FNV patch can solve this problem. Instructions on how to do that are [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_patches#Removing_patches).

After finishing that, you can reapply the newest patch.